# Sharepoint 2007 per User Homepage

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a Sharepoint 2007 server with lots of sites and lots of users.  I'd like to be able to associate each user with their own default home page when they log in.  IE: User1 goes to Site1 when they log in and User2 goes to Site2 every time they log in.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Stu

Answer (score 1):

Stu,

I'm assuming you're in an authenticated intranet-style environment.  Correct?

Do you leverage MySites?  It would be a relatively easy thing to do to establish a redirect to a user's MySites page upon landing on a site.  Provided you have the default self-service site creation for MySites enabled, new users will have the site generated for them upon redirect if it doesn't exist.

Aside from that, I would say that there isn't an easy way to "route" a user to a particular page based on their user identity without writing some custom code.  You might be able to coerce MOSS' audiences capabilities to do something in conjunction with something like a Content Editor WebPart per destination, but even saying that makes me feel a little dirty (and certainly wouldn't be easy or maintainable).

My current client has a very large Internet-based MOSS presence, and I actually wrote this very same type of functionality for them; rather than user identity, it uses some other factors and a rules engine to determine where a user should be directed to.  It wasn't particularly hard to do, but it was custom code (which I assume you're trying to avoid).

For what it's worth!

Answer (score 0):

Stu,

We are doing something kind of similar - I can describe it - and see if it gets you any closer.  It's definitely a "think outside the box" solution.

What we wanted to do, is create a webpage that shows users a list of the 10 or 20 out of 200+ teamsites that they have permissions to get to.

That list is going to be different for each person - and changes as they move from team to team as well as when new teams are created or disbanded.

So...we create a page w/ a Search Core Results web part - and then set the Fixed Keyword Query to use ContentClass:STS_Site.  Gives us a nice list which we can then configure to display what we want.  Its updated when the team sites are indexed so it's dynamic and personalized for the user.

Now - as I said - this is NOT to straight solution to your request - however, you could borrow from this idea to create a page w/ a search results page and fixed query that returns the sites you are trying to steer them toward.  They'd still need to click to get there - but at least the link would be there and it would be customized.

Hopefully this gets you where you want to be - or closer anyway.